# D3.js bounding box issue - Force tick function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm in the process of learning D3 and I've come across an issue I can't seem to resolve.

I'm working with some code from rveciana's [Circles bouncing inside a rectangle example](http://bl.ocks.org/rveciana/6184054), which I have stripped of some of its bounciness.

I am attempting to get the nodes/circles to sinking to the bottom of the container and be bound to the inside of the box, however, when I replace the attributes of the circles in the tick function from:

```
.attr("cx", function(d) {return d.x;})  
.attr("cy", function(d) {return d.y;});
```

to:

```
.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, d.x)); });  
.attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.y)); });
```

the nodes/circles are positioned at 0,0 rather than randomly in the container, and cannot be interacted with or moved.

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/Glitttttch/p93qyh99/3/, with the two new lines commented out.

```
function tick(e) {  
force.alpha(0.1)  
circle  
.each(gravity(e.alpha))  
.each(collide(.5))  
.attr("cx", function(d) {return d.x;})  
.attr("cy", function(d) {return d.y;});  
//.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(radius, Math.min(width -    radius, d.x)); });  
//.attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.y)); });
```

}

Any suggestions on how to correctly integrate those lines is very very much appreciated.

Comment: According to Bostock's code for [Bounded Force Layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492), the assignment and definition are necessary for setting up the bounding box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are using `radius`, which is a scale. That's the reason why you are getting so many NaN (the most common reason to get SVG elements at the origin).

The solution is simple, just change `radius` for `d.radius`:

```
.attr("cx", function(d) { 
    return d.x = Math.max(d.radius, Math.min(width - d.radius, d.x)); 
})
.attr("cy", function(d) { 
    return d.y = Math.max(d.radius, Math.min(height - d.radius, d.y)); 
});
```

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/03smjfo8/

Comment: Oh that's interesting, and totally makes sense.

I really appreciate the help!